# wx Python subclass Dialog

Tags: python, wxpython, subclass

I have a source file containing the following:

```
 class Dialog1 ( wx.Dialog ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):

        wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Hello", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 342,253 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )
```

Im trying to instantiate this in another source file like so:

```
dlg = Dialog1(wx.Dialog).__init__(self, None)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scripts\motors\motors.py", line 281, in onListOption
dlg = Dialog1(wx.Dialog).__init__(self, None)
File "...",
line 21, in __init__
    wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Hello", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 342,253 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_windows.py", line 734, in __init__
_windows_.Dialog_swiginit(self,_windows_.new_Dialog(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: in method 'new_Dialog', expected argument 1 of type 'wxWindow *'
```

Any idea why this is happening? I have tried passing `wx.Window` to the Dialog init but it doesnt make a difference. Can't someon explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dlg = Dialog1(parent_window)`

is the way to go. Where `parent_window` will be the parent of the dialog. See [classes in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Quoting from the link:

> When a class defines an **init**() method, class instantiation
>   automatically invokes **init**() for the newly-created class instance.

Here is a working minimal code snippet:

```
import wx

class Dialog1 ( wx.Dialog ):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Hello",
            pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 342,253 ),
            style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )

app = wx.App()
dlg = Dialog1(None)
dlg.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. .Still getting the same error

Comment: @enrm see my edit, i added a working code snippet. You should be missing something.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work now. Don't really know what I made differently this time or if the compiled file was old or something. Nevertheless, works now.